# How to call UI class in Qt5 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, qt-creator, pyqt5

This is the class that have to call the UI class:

```
class mainpanelManager(QtGui.QGuiApplication, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGuiApplication.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainpanelManager()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and this is the UI class(generated from QtCreator and Qt5.7):

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1155, 704)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 16777215))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listView, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.listWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.tab)
        self.listWidget_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.listWidget_2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.listWidget_2.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.listWidget_2.setModelColumn(0)
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.listWidget_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 130))
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 100))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalSlider_2 = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.horizontalSlider_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 40))
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 16777215))
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setObjectName("horizontalSlider_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_2.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_2.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_3.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_3.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
        self.pushButton_3.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_4.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_4.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.pushButton_4.setText("")
        self.pushButton_4.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_5.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton_5.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.pushButton_5.setText("")
        self.pushButton_5.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 180))
        self.label_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 180))
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalSlider_3 = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider_3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider_3.setObjectName("horizontalSlider_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider_3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.pushButton_6.setText("")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.pushButton_7.setText("")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.pushButton_8.setText("")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_8)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1155, 19))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuSettings = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuSettings.setObjectName("menuSettings")
        self.menuLibrary = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuSettings)
        self.menuLibrary.setObjectName("menuLibrary")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionOpen_Dir = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_Dir.setObjectName("actionOpen_Dir")
        self.actionMinimize = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionMinimize.setObjectName("actionMinimize")
        self.actionClose = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose.setObjectName("actionClose")
        self.actionGeneral = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionGeneral.setObjectName("actionGeneral")
        self.actionRefresh = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRefresh.setObjectName("actionRefresh")
        self.actionRebuild = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRebuild.setObjectName("actionRebuild")
        self.actionClear = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClear.setObjectName("actionClear")
        self.actionSettings = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSettings.setObjectName("actionSettings")
        self.actionAbout_Siren = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout_Siren.setObjectName("actionAbout_Siren")
        self.actionCheck_for_updates = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionCheck_for_updates.setObjectName("actionCheck_for_updates")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_Dir)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionMinimize)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClose)
        self.menuLibrary.addAction(self.actionRefresh)
        self.menuLibrary.addAction(self.actionRebuild)
        self.menuLibrary.addAction(self.actionClear)
        self.menuLibrary.addAction(self.actionSettings)
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.menuLibrary.menuAction())
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.actionGeneral)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionAbout_Siren)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionCheck_for_updates)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuSettings.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.valueChanged['int'].connect(self.label_2.setNum)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.listWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Artist"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Album"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuSettings.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
        self.menuLibrary.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Library"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionOpen_Dir.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Dir..."))
        self.actionMinimize.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Minimize"))
        self.actionClose.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))
        self.actionGeneral.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "General"))
        self.actionRefresh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Refresh"))
        self.actionRebuild.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Rebuild"))
        self.actionClear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.actionSettings.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
        self.actionAbout_Siren.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "About Siren"))
        self.actionCheck_for_updates.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check for updates"))
```

When i run the `class mainpanelManager` i get this error:

```
QtGui.QGuiApplication.__init__(self)
TypeError: QGuiApplication(List[str]): not enough arguments
```

Please give me some advice how to run the UI class from the other class.
What am i doing wrong?? The samples i found were using `import PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets` but in my case (using Qt5) there is no `QApplication` option like in `Qt4`. Seems `Qt5` uses `QtGui.QGuiApplication`. I can't understand this. Any help will be welcome. Please explain in details. I am still quite new in Python.

Comment: That's a lot of code there. Maybe you could make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subclass which matches the top-level object from Qt Designer - which in this case appears to be a `QMainWindow`:

```
class mainpanelManager(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

And you should use a `QApplication`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainpanelManager()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PS:

PyQt4 is not compatible with PyQt5. See: [Differences Between PyQt4 and PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html).

PPS:

It also looks like you've attempted to edit the module generated by pyuic. Do not ever do that. I suggest you re-run pyuic so you get a clean module.